# How to load invoice record in SuiteScript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

```
require(['N/search','N/record'])

var search = require('N/search')
var record = require('N/record')
var invoice = record.load({
      type: record.Type.INVOICE,
      id: 444283
    })

log.debug('invoice',invoice)
```

Hi everyone can someone heelp me figure out how to properly load invoice records, vendor bills/credits ? i try this simple record.load with this enum type and i get errors of:

"name":"INVALID_TRANS_TYP","message":"Transaction type specified is incorrect.",

Answer (score 1):

That error would seem to indicate that the Transaction with Internal ID `444283` is not actually an Invoice. Verify your internal ID and transaction type match up.